# How do I show installed fonts supporting a specific Unicode character/range?

Tags: fonts

Is there any way to produce a list of those installed fonts that contain a specific Unicode character or character range?

When dealing with characters in foreign scripts (e.g. runes, Phoenician characters, variant CJK Ideographs) it can be hard to remember which fonts support those particular ranges. And with about 300 fonts installed, it's rather a hassle to go through them all manually to check. Back when I was using Windows, I had a program that could query the installed fonts and then give a list of those which supported a given character/range (BabelMap). Is there anything similar for Linux?